# How can I create a way for my repository to do an Upsert?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6.1.  I have a repository with these Insert and Update methods:

```
    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        ((IObjectState) entity).ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;
        _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        _context.SyncObjectState(entity);
    }
    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        ((IObjectState) entity).ObjectState = ObjectState.Modified;
        _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        _context.SyncObjectState(entity);
    }
```

These are called from my controller with:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Exam exam)
    {
        try
        {
            _examService.Insert(exam);
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
            return Request.CreateResponse<Exam>(HttpStatusCode.Created, exam);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, ex);
        }
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, Exam exam)
    {
        if (id != exam.ExamId)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        try
        {
            _examService.Update(exam);
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
            return Request.CreateResponse<Exam>(HttpStatusCode.OK, exam);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }

    }
```

and in my service layer:

```
    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        _repository.Insert(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        _repository.Update(entity);
    }
```

I have a problem as there is a case where my application wants to do an update but there may be no object in the database to update. In this case I would like my code to do an insert instead.

Is there a way this is normally handled with a repository pattern?  I read about Oracle and they have an upsert command.  However I am using SQL Server 2012 and a service layer and repository.  What would be a good way for me to do this? I would really like to have some way of trying an update and if it then fails doing an insert as 99% of the time the object will be present for me to update it.

Comment: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/05/03/the-key-to-addorupdate/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately EF 6.x does not yet have UPSERT feature.

EF will generate update query if the entity's primary key is set or insert query if not set.

```
public virtual void Save(TEntity entity)
{
    // assuming TEntity as property "Id" [Key] of type int
    ((IObjectState) entity).ObjectState = entity.Id <= 0 ? ObjectState.Added : ObjectState.Modified;
    _dbSet.Attach(entity);
    _context.SyncObjectState(entity);
}
```

When updating an entity not present in the database, set the "Id" to "0".

Comment: The problem is I do not know if the entity is present in the database.  I need a way to fallback if the update fails and to do an insert in that instance.